# Confusing use of word "becoming"

Tags: grammar, adjectives

> His status is attested by his becoming an alderman.

Can you please explain the meaning of this sentence? Specially in this part: "his becoming an alderman"

Comment: Have you looked up “become” in a dictionary?  I’m sure there’s a definition that fits.

Comment: @Jim , Yes I have and found that it act as an adjective and a noun but still not clear regarding this sentence. Reference: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/becoming

Comment: (copula) to come to be; develop or grow into; he became a monster  In your case he became alderman.  He wasn’t one, and then he became one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive adjective/determiner?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner) 'his becoming an alderman' is an example of the POSS-ing construction, where an ing-form (CGEL gerund-participial) is preceded by a possessive pronoun (etc). So 'his becoming an alderman' (cf 'his success') rather than 'him becoming an alderman' (the ACC-ing counterpart).

Comment: You could also take a look here: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/347621/195517

Answer (score -4):

He is becoming an alderman.
He wasn't an alderman but he is undergoing a process to become it, in a while he will be an alderman.

Comment: That would be "He's becoming an alderman". The OP's sentence means "The fact that he became an alderman shows that he is/was of high status".